# Pandas read_csv errors on number of fields, but visual inspection looks fine

Tags: mysql, pandas

I'm trying to load a large csv file, 3,715,259 lines.
I created this file myself and there are 9 fields separated by commas.

Here's the error:

```
df = pd.read_csv("avaya_inventory_rev2.csv", error_bad_lines=False)

Skipping line 2924525: expected 9 fields, saw 11
Skipping line 2924526: expected 9 fields, saw 10
Skipping line 2924527: expected 9 fields, saw 10
Skipping line 2924528: expected 9 fields, saw 10
```

This doesn't make sense to me, I inspected the offending lines using:

```
sed -n "2924524,2924525p" infile.csv
```

I can't list the outputs as they contain proprietary information for a client. I'll try to synthesize a meaningful replacement.

Lines 2924524 and 2924525 look to have to same number of fields to me.

Also, I was able to load the same file into a mySQL table with no error.

```
create table Inventory (path varchar (255), isText int, ext varchar(5), type varchar(100), size int, sloc int, comments int, blank int, tot_lines int);
```

I don't know enough about mySQL to understand why that may or maynot be a valid test and why pandas would have a different outcome from loading the same file.

TIA !

'''UPDATE''': I tried to read with the engine='python':

```
Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

When I create this csv, I'm using a shell script I wrote. I feed lines to the file with redirect  >>

I tried the suggested fix:

```
input = open(input, 'rU')
df.read_csv(input, engine='python')
```

Back to the same error:

```
ValueError: Expected 9 fields in line 5157, saw 11
```

I'm guessing it has to do with my csv creation script and how I dealt with 
quoting in that. I don't know how to investigate this further.

I opened the csv input file in vim and on line 5157 there's a `^M` which google says it Windows CR.

OK...I'm closer, although I did kinda suspect something like this and used `dos2unix` on the csv intput.

I removed the `^M` using vim, and re-ran with same error about
11 fields. However, I can now see the 11 fields where as before I just saw
9. There's `v`'s which is likely some kind of Windows hold over ?

SUMMARY: SOme somebody thought it'd be cute to name files with `fobar.sh,v`

So my profiler didn't mess up it's was just a name weirdness...plus the random \cr\lf from windows that snuck in....

Cheers

Comment: Well it's impossible for me to tell you other than the obvious (check those problem lines i.e. just try loading those lines) how to fix this without seeing sample data to reproduce the issue

Comment: if you are comfortable at the command line (looks like you are), you might try counting commas to make sure things are as expected.

Comment: I tried again with the engine='python' and recieved: Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?